# general query regarding a vba code to identify a range with a specific string. (string can be in a list form)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So, let me give a brief introduction about the topic. I just started #vba coding and I have this project in which there are number of worksheets in excel. I copied these worksheets to one worksheet. Now everything is in one big table. Suppose [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh5r0.png): first ten rows have XNBD01(first column in image) and next 13 rows have XNBD03 and then 11 rows have XNBDXX.

Now I want to first create a range to select just whole column across row names with XNB01 and perform some calculation. what could be the code to search the row name and fix a parameter so that, the calculation is applied only within the fixed range i.e only rows containing XNB01. Basically how to identify the first XNB01 area and then just sum the number of objects in column 3(in image). and then jump to next number.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's unclear what calculation you're trying to perform but it sounds like `=*IF()` formulas like `=SUMIF()` or `=SUMIFS()` could be useful. I would also recommend looking into Power Query.

Comment: I have started with vba coding, I am searching for the right method.

Comment: thank you for your input, I will see these functions, if they work